How to use a divider logic to change the size of the window?
I use the Ctrl w< to change the size of the windows. When the window size change a divider moves.
As long that the current window is not at the extreme right of the tab the divider moves left (which match with <).
But if the window is at the extreme right then the divider moves left which is in-intuitive with to me (< drives you to think it will move left).
Remark: I understand that original logic is about window size and that the logic that is more intuitive to me is a divider logic.
How could change that?

I came with the following solution:
function! s:right_ids(layout, right)
  let type = a:layout[0] 
  if type ==# 'leaf'
    if a:right
      return [a:layout[1]]
    else
      return []
    endif
  elseif type ==# 'col'
    let ret = []
    for sublayout in a:layout[1]
      let ret = ret + s:right_ids(sublayout, a:right)
    endfor
    return ret
  elseif type ==# 'row'
    let ret = []
    for index in range(len(a:layout[1]))
      let sublayout = a:layout[1][index]
      let right = 0
      if index == len(a:layout[1]) - 1
        let right = 1
      endif
      let ret = ret + s:right_ids(sublayout, right)
    endfor
    return ret
  endif
endfunction

function! s:bottom_ids(layout, bottom)
  let type = a:layout[0] 
  if type ==# 'leaf'
    if a:bottom
      return [a:layout[1]]
    else
      return []
    endif
  elseif type ==# 'row'
    let ret = []
    for sublayout in a:layout[1]
      let ret = ret + s:bottom_ids(sublayout, a:bottom)
    endfor
    return ret
  elseif type ==# 'col'
    let ret = []
    for index in range(len(a:layout[1]))
      let sublayout = a:layout[1][index]
      let bottom = 0
      if index == len(a:layout[1]) - 1
        let bottom = 1
      endif
      let ret = ret + s:bottom_ids(sublayout, bottom)
    endfor
    return ret
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> <C-w>< index(<SID>right_ids(winlayout(), 0), win_getid()) >= 0 ? "<C-w>>" : "<C-w><lt>"
nnoremap <expr> <C-w>> index(<SID>right_ids(winlayout(), 0), win_getid()) >= 0 ? "<C-w><lt>" : "<C-w>>"
nnoremap <expr> <C-w>- index(<SID>bottom_ids(winlayout(), 0), win_getid()) >= 0 ? "<C-w>-" : "<C-w>+"
nnoremap <expr> <C-w>+ index(<SID>bottom_ids(winlayout(), 0), win_getid()) >= 0 ? "<C-w>+" : "<C-w>-"

In this solution:

Ctrl W< moves a divider left
Ctrl W> moves a divider right
Ctrl W- moves a divider down
Ctrl W+ moves a divider up
The divider selected is the same as in the original key command (just the sense is affected)


Just resize the adjacent window instead
nnoremap <expr><C-W>< printf("\<cmd>vert %dresize%+d\r", winnr('h'), -v:count1)
nnoremap <expr><C-W>> printf("\<cmd>vert %dresize%+d\r", winnr('h'), v:count1)
nnoremap <expr><C-W>- printf("\<cmd>%dresize%+d\r", winnr('k'), -v:count1)
nnoremap <expr><C-W>+ printf("\<cmd>%dresize%+d\r", winnr('k'), v:count1)


Thanks! It is a nice solution. It doesn't need the win_getid() API. It works fine but in case you have three windows the moving divider is now the left one and not the right one as in the standard Vim behavior (it is more invasive).

@VivianDeSmedt You can fiddle with winnr(h/j/k/l) and +-count to get slightly different behaviour. But, given a layout complex enough, there'll be some problems and incompatibilities, for sure.
